# External hard drive re-formatted for mac (FAT32) but not working on windows

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have a 2TB external hard drive, that I originally bought to store all my files from my old (Sony VAIO vista) laptop, as my new (Macbook pro) doesn't have as big a storage capacity. It was working fine, having saved lots of files onto it, until I decided to back up my mac, which deleted all the files.

I then partitioned the file into FAT32 files, and tried to plug it back into windows, but it won't recognise it in the 'computer' section. The funny thing is, is that it is in the disk management but I can't do anything with it.

Anyone got any ideas?

Here is what it looks like when I go on disk management:

[image: 1]

Comment: If you want to post an image, upload it somewhere else and link to it here. Can you not right-click it in Disk Management?

Comment: I can right click it but the only options it gives are 'help' and 'delete volume'

Comment: Here is how it looks in Disk Management:
http://la911.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1

Comment: "la911's images are not publicly available."

Comment: AH sorry will sort that out

Comment: This should work http://imgur.com/gallery/2Tt09dR

Comment: I'm not familiar with the drive formatting tool on MACs, but it looks to me like you used a MSDOS partition table, but some other kind of file system.  Either, windows is recognizing your partition table, but not your filesystem(s).

Comment: @smokes2345 Thanks, do you know what filesystem I'd have to use to get it to work?

Comment: If there's no unrecoverable data on those partitions and you're bound to make them work in windows I'd just delete the partitions (volumes in windows terms) right there in disk management.  Once you've deleted them windows should give you options to partition and format.  On a disk that size I would use NTFS, not FAT32, provided your mac can read it.

Comment: @smokes2345 On the right partition is a backup of my mac, the point of me doing this was to get it to work on both computers, should It work on the mac if I partition on windows?

Comment: I know FAT32 will work on just about anything, it's ancient.  I know macs will at least read NTFS, older models it took a bit of a hack to enable writes, but i'm not sure about newer models.

Comment: It looks like Windows thinks there's something wrong with the drive. You might be able to mount it using CMD, though: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757491%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you can't "do anything to it" in Windows is because you haven't unmounted the drive yet that's why you're options to take on the drive are greyed out.

As to why Windows will not recognize it I'm sure that it's due to the drive being formatted under OS X which has set the HDD to be either GUID or Apple Partition Map. And you need it to be Master Boot Record. If you use Disk Utility in OS X and select "disk info" on the HDD it'll tell you. And if needed you'll need to reformat it as Master Boot Record. Make sure you've copied all your files on the disk as this will delete them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have reformatted it in the mac like you said, and it now works on my sony as well as the mac. I have accepted your answer but I can't vote up as I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Hey no worries glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows doesn't like fat32 formatted devices with a GPT partition table like OS X puts them. Try setting it back to MSDOS.